# How to implements a interface to a controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, request, laravel-6

I trying to implements a interface to a controller but when i try that, the request is converted into a string.
Here is the code of the controller:

```
class FilesController extends Controller implements Repository
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->factory = new RepositoryFactoryImp();
    }


    public function index($request)
    {
        $repository = $this->factory->createRepository($request->type_repository);

        return $repository->getFilesList($request);
    }
}
```

Here is the code of the interface:

```
interface Repository
{
    public function index(GetFileListRequest $request);
}
```

Then the error that i get is:

> ErrorException: Trying to get property 'type_repository' of non-object
>   in file
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pocs\repository\app\Http\Controllers\FilesController.php
>   on line 31

I do a dd($request); and the result is a string, the string is the content of type_repository variable of the route:

```
Route::get('files/{type_repository}', 'filesController@index');
```

What can be the problem? Is possible to implements a interface to a controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well to get started you haven't injected the request in your controller:

```
class FilesController extends Controller implements Repository
{
    // ...


    public function index($request) // <-----
    { //                  ^^^^^^^^^
        $repository = $this->factory->createRepository($request->type_repository);

        return $repository->getFilesList($request);
    }
}
```

Try doing this instead:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

// ...

    public function index(Request $request) { ... }
    //                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

### Side note

As an observation, you have declared the `index()` method in your interface but you are calling the `createRepository()` one in your implementation.

Comment: Yeah! that's the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @jdoe1980 glad to help, you can accept the answer now :)